# Customizing the sidebar in beamer having aligned section numbers

Tags: beamer, align

I'd like to know how the vertical navigation in the `beamer` sidebar can be edited to have the section numbers aligned left like in a toc.

The question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/customizing-the-sidebar-in-beamer) I think the MWE can be used, too.

To make clearer what I want to achieve I uploaded a picture of a beamer theme (non-public) having the alignment implemented:

[image]

As you can see the section number is fixed left of section title and the subsection starts at the exact same x-position like the section. Also line break start at that x-position. Also other texts like title are fixed at this position.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using side-by-side `\parbox`es for the numbers and the titles; change `\secinsidebarindent` (dafault=`10pt`) to control the width of the box reserved for the numbers:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Marburg}

\newlength\secinsidebarindent
\setlength\secinsidebarindent{10pt}

\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    \vskip4em%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
  }%

  \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \defbeamertemplate*{sidebar right}{sidebar theme}
    {%
      \vfill%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt}
  \fi

\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar}%{sidebar theme}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar}{%
      \parbox[t]{\secinsidebarindent}{\insertsectionheadnumber\hfill}%
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\beamer@sidebarwidth-\secinsidebarindent-6pt\relax}{\raggedright\insertsectionhead}}%
  }%
}
\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}%{sidebar theme}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar shaded}{%
      \parbox[t]{\secinsidebarindent}{\insertsectionheadnumber\hfill}%
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\beamer@sidebarwidth-\secinsidebarindent-6pt\relax}{\raggedright\insertsectionhead}}%
  }%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar}%{sidebar theme}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip2ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{subsection in sidebar}{%
      \parbox[t]{\secinsidebarindent}{\hfill}%
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\beamer@sidebarwidth-\secinsidebarindent-6pt\relax}{\raggedright\insertsubsectionhead}}%
  }%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}%{sidebar theme}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip2ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{subsection in sidebar shaded}{%
      \parbox[t]{\secinsidebarindent}{\hfill}%
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\beamer@sidebarwidth-\secinsidebarindent-6pt\relax}{\raggedright\insertsubsectionhead}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First test section with a long title}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}

\section{Second test section with another long title}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}

\section{Yet another section}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image showing the resulting sidebar:

[image]