# Beamer, including links in the sidebar

Tags: beamer

I need to access links from several locations in the presentation.

Instead of repeating inserting the links in those several locations, I put them in the last slide, and access them, when needed, by going to this last slide.

For easier accessing those links, is it possible to insert them in the sidebar, instead of putting them in the last slide!

Another issue, why when I uncomment the line

```
\label{linka}
```

the compilation stops?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
% begin Section/Subsection pages control -----------------
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
 \begingroup
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=10pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}
   \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
 \end{beamercolorbox}
 \endgroup
}
%
\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}
{
 \begingroup
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=2pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{section title}
   \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
 \end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace*{-2.5pt}
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,rounded=true,shadow=true]{subsection title}
   \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\insertsubsection\par
 \end{beamercolorbox}
\endgroup
}
%
\setbeamerfont{section title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subsection title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
% end Section/Subsection pages control -----------------
\begin{document}
% begin Section
\section
[sec1]{Section1}
\frame{\sectionpage}
% begin frame
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle
{Cross Section at a}
hello {\textcolor{green}{linka}}
\hypertarget{linka}
%    \label{linka}
hello
\end{frame} 
% end frame
%
% begin Section
\section
[sec2]{Section2}
\frame{\sectionpage}
% begin frame
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle
{Cross Section at b}
hello {\textcolor{blue}{linkb}}
\hypertarget{linkb}
%    \label{linkb}
hello
\end{frame} 
% end frame
%
% begin Section
\section
[sec3]{Section3}
\frame{\sectionpage}
% begin frame
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle
{Cross Section at c}
hello {\textcolor{brown}{linkc}}
\hypertarget{linkc}
%    \label{linkc}
hello
\end{frame} 
% end frame
%
% begin Section
\section
[sec4]{Section4}
\frame{\sectionpage}
% begin frame
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle
{Cross Section at d}
hello {\textcolor{red}{linkd}}
\hypertarget{linkd}
%    \label{linkd}
hello
\end{frame} 
% end frame
%
% begin frame
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle
{Links}
{\hyperlink{linka}{\textcolor{green}{linka}}}

{\hyperlink{linkb}{\textcolor{blue}{linkb}}}

{\hyperlink{linkc}{\textcolor{brown}{linkc}}}

{\hyperlink{linkd}{\textcolor{red}{linkd}}}
\end{frame} 
% end frame
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/customizing-the-sidebar-in-beamer?rq=1 help? It's a different theme, but the method should be the same.

Comment: @Hany Please only ask about one problem per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add something to the existing sidebar, you could use `\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar left}{<stuff before the existing sidebar>}{<stuff after the existing sidebar>}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}{%
  \usebeamerfont{section in sidebar}%
  ~\hyperlink{linka}{\textcolor{green}{linka}}\par\medskip
  ~\hyperlink{linkb}{\textcolor{cyan}{linkb}}\par\medskip
  ~\hyperlink{linkc}{\textcolor{brown}{linkc}}\par\medskip
  ~\hyperlink{linkd}{\textcolor{red}{linkd}}\par
  \vfill
}

\begin{document}

\section[sec1]{Section1}

\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle{Cross Section at a}
  hello \textcolor{green}{linka}
  \hypertarget{linka}
  hello
\end{frame} 

\section[sec2]{Section2}
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle{Cross Section at b}
  hello \textcolor{blue}{linkb}
  \hypertarget{linkb}
  hello
\end{frame} 

\section[sec3]{Section3}
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle{Cross Section at c}
  hello \textcolor{brown}{linkc}
  \hypertarget{linkc}
  hello
\end{frame} 

\section[sec4]{Section4}
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle{Cross Section at d}
  hello \textcolor{red}{linkd}
  \hypertarget{linkd}
  hello
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]